# SQL Server Xquery sql:variable usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I need to use a dynamic string for an xquery path but .query/.nodes methods require a literal string as parameter. So I decided to try sql:variable

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML, @node varchar(max)
SET @xmlData =  'Some XML Here'
SET @node = '/path1/path2/path3'
```

When I query with

```
select @xmlData.query('/path1/path2/path3')
```

It returns the intended result

But when I query with

```
select @xmlData.query('sql:variable("@node")')
```

It returns the variable value itself as "/path1/path2/path3"

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```sql
select @xmlData.query('/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@node")]')
```

It matches any node with a wildcard `*`, but there is an extra predicate that the name has to match the variable

---

For performance reasons, you should preferably use `/text()` to get inner text, and use `.values` to get a single value.

```sql
select @xmlData.value('(/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@node")]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
```

Comment: Actually the path I'm using has multiple levels with namespaces like
"Envelope/Body//return/NS:dataset/NS:row"
a single * doesn't seem to cover it

Answer (score 0):

`sql:variable` is used to substitute a single scalar variable into an XPath expression, so can't be used to define a full path. You can use it to test against a single node's name, though, e.g.:

```sql
declare @xmlData XML = '<path1><path2><path3>foo</path3></path2></path1>'
select [example1] = @xmlData.query('/path1/path2/path3')

--example1
--<path3>foo</path3>

declare @node1 varchar(max) = 'path1'
declare @node2 varchar(max) = 'path2'
declare @node3 varchar(max) = 'path3'
select [example2] = @xmlData.query('//*[local-name()= sql:variable("@node1")]/*[local-name()= sql:variable("@node2")]/*[local-name()= sql:variable("@node3")]');

--example2
--<path3>foo</path3>
```